# Javascript checking for object properties in a nested array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two main objects that I am dealing with here. One is called `tasks` that is an array of objects. The other is called `userSelectedRoles` which is an array of role ID's.

Within my tasks array, there is a property called `Roles` which is also an array of objects.

I am trying to see if the `userSelectedRoles` exist in any of the tasks, and if not, add them to it.

I created some pseudo I was trying to wrap my head around it.

**Example:**

```
var userSelectedRoles = [1, 2, 3],
  tasks = [{
    TaskName: 'Task 1',
    TaskID: 1,
    Roles: [{
      RoleName: 'Role1',
      RoleID: 1
    }, {
      RoleName: 'Role 2',
      RoleID: 2
    }]
  }, {
    TaskName: 'Task 2',
    TaskID: 2,
    Roles: [{
      RoleName: 'Role1',
      RoleID: 1
    }, {
      RoleName: 'Role 3',
      RoleID: 3
    }]
  }]


// Loop over our tasks
for (var t = 0; t < tasks.length; t++) {

  // Loop over the roles
  for (var r = 0; r < tasks[t].Roles.length; r++) {

    // Loop over our user selected roles
    for (var sr = 0; sr < userSelectedRoles.length; sr++) {

      // If this user selected role exists within our roles, continue
      if (tasks[t].Roles[r].RoleID == userSelectedRoles[sr]) {
        // This role exists, no need to do anything
      } else {
        // This user selected role does not exist in our tasks, we need to add it
        tasks[t].Roles.push({
          RoleName: 'Blah',
          RoleID: userSelectedRoles[sr]
        })
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The above code isn't working, crashed my fiddle so I assume I have a loop wrong somewhere.

Is there an easier way to do this without having to do all the loops perhaps?

The end goal here is that a new role would be added to both tasks. `Task 1 = Role 3` & `Task 2 = Role 2`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table and collect the id, you have. Then iterate the `userSelectedRoles` and if not set, then push the object to `Roles`.

```js
var userSelectedRoles = [1, 2, 3],
    tasks = [{ TaskName: 'Task 1', TaskID: 1, Roles: [{ RoleName: 'Role1', RoleID: 1 }, { RoleName: 'Role 2', RoleID: 2 }] }, { TaskName: 'Task 2', TaskID: 2, Roles: [{ RoleName: 'Role1', RoleID: 1 }, { RoleName: 'Role 3', RoleID: 3 }] }];

tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    var roleIds = Object.create(null);
    task.Roles.forEach(function (role) {
        roleIds[role.RoleID] = true;
    });
    userSelectedRoles.forEach(function (id) {
        if (!roleIds[id]) {
            task.Roles.push({ RoleName: 'Blah', RoleID: id });
        }
    });
});

console.log(tasks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var userSelectedRoles = [1, 2, 3],
    tasks = [{ TaskName: 'Task 1', TaskID: 1, Roles: [{ RoleName: 'Role1', RoleID: 1 }, { RoleName: 'Role 2', RoleID: 2 }] }, { TaskName: 'Task 2', TaskID: 2, Roles: [{ RoleName: 'Role1', RoleID: 1 }, { RoleName: 'Role 3', RoleID: 3 }] }];

tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    var ids = new Set(task.Roles.map(({ RoleID }) => RoleID));
    userSelectedRoles.forEach(id => ids.has(id) || task.Roles.push({ RoleName: 'Blah', RoleID: id }));
});

console.log(tasks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This seems a bit too much, wouldn't a simple array work just as well, and is easier to construct?

Comment: then you have too look up in the array if the id is given. object or set has a faster access.

Comment: Although I don't know, its kind of subjective. I made a test here http://jsfiddle.net/asosnovsky/PGfgv/3627/ if you increase the number of ids to check, my array example is faster. If you increase the number of documents to check, then yes, your Set method is faster. I guess we both right :P

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this? (I always hated using for-loops, adds additional variables we don't need i.e. the index)

```
tasks.forEach(task => {
  var roleIds = task.Roles.map(r=>r.RoleID);
  userSelectedRoles.forEach( r => {
   if(roleIds.indexOf(r) === -1){
     task.Roles.push({RoleID: r, RoleName: 'blah'})
   }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where the mistake is... In the last loop, you add items to the Role. This means that the loop at 1 level higher will now make 1 more loop. And this loop will add a new role, which will make it loop one more time, wich will add one more role - I think you got it now :)

Solution using this same structure: store the length in a variable before starting the loop, and use that for the number of loops to do.

```
for (var t = 0; t < tasks.length; t++) {
  //CHANGED CODE START
  let rolesLength = task[t].Roles.length;
  // Loop over the roles
  for (var r = 0; r < rolesLength ; r++) {
    //CHANGED CODE END
    // Loop over our user selected roles
    for (var sr = 0; sr < userSelectedRoles.length; sr++) {

      // If this user selected role exists within our roles, continue
      if (tasks[t].Roles[r].RoleID == userSelectedRoles[sr]) {
        // This role exists, no need to do anything
      } else {
        // This user selected role does not exist in our tasks, we need to add it
        tasks[t].Roles.push({
          RoleName: 'Blah',
          RoleID: userSelectedRoles[sr]
        })
      }
    }

  }
}
```